# inconsistent behavior with erasing map iterators in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, erase

I'm very confused by the behavior of the erase function for maps. In the simple example below, the code outputs "224". However, if you comment out the line "m['e'] = 5", it outputs "221". Neither result makes sense to me. Can someone explain the logic here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main(){

        map<char, int> m;
        m['a'] = 1;
        m['b'] = 2;
        m['c'] = 3;
        m['d'] = 4;
        m['e'] = 5;

        map<char, int>::iterator it = m.begin();        it++; 
        cout << it->second;                             
        m.erase(it); 
        cout << it->second;
        it++;
        cout << it->second << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use an iterator after erasing it. It is invalid and the behaviour is not determined (crash, wriong value ?):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase

Comment: Ok, that explains it. However, aren't you allowed to use vector iterators after erasing?

Comment: Even less, quoting [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase): Iterators and references to the erased elements and to the elements between them and the end of the container are invalidated. The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

Comment: @user2990344 Nope, even with `vector` you're not allowed to use an iterator to an element after erasing that element. However, depending on *your definition* of expected behavior, doing so with a `vector` *might* work as you want it to. But a `map` is a totally different beast as far as memory layout is concerned, and it is practically guaranteed re-using that iterator will not produce the intended result.

Comment: Also, I've found that I can get the behavior that I naively expect by doing the following:
- find the iterator I want to erase,
- copy the iterator,
- increment the copy,
- erase the original,
- use the copy,
Is this commonly done?

Comment: Yes, it is one of the most common erase pattern.

Comment: @user2990344 C++11 modified [`map::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) to return an iterator to the element following the one that was erased. You can use that if your compiler supports it.

Comment: @user2990344 "copy the iterator, - increment the copy, - erase the original, - use the copy" sounds too complicated, on reality it is as simple as `map.erase(it++);`

Comment: @Slava Okay now I'm really confused. I thought that's exactly the thing I'm not supposed to do. If I'm supposed to do this, can you try running the code in my original post, and explaining why I get inconsistent results when I comment out the line setting the fifth element of m?

Comment: postfix operator++ creates a copy "under the hood" and returns it. prefix operator++ does not creates a copy. @Slava I would not recommend someone use it before understanding what it really does.

Comment: Just because I do not know if this is clear: `it++` => postfix operator with copy under the hood/ `++it` => prefix operator without copy

Comment: Can someone explain to me whether there's a difference between
erase(it++);
and
erase(it); it++?
because the latter definitely does not work

Comment: Here a naive postfix operator implematation: `iterator operator++(int /* asked to diff signature with prefix iterator */) { iterator tmp = *this; ++this; return tmp; }`. As you see *there is a copy inside the postfix `operator++`. That's why it works when you're doing `erase(it++)`, `erase()`is working on the copy returned by the postfix operator.

Comment: @Johan I would not recommend someone to use C++ before understanding what it really does.

Answer (score 0):

```
map<char, int>::iterator it = m.begin();        it++; 
cout << it->second;                             
m.erase(it);  // (1) 
cout << it->second; // (2)
it++; // (3)
cout << it->second << endl;
```

You have invalidated the iterator at position `(1)`, so attempting to dereference it in `(2)` and `(3)` is undefined behavior.  It is virtually identical to deleting a pointer and then then attempting to dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

To erase elements in map for pre c++11 you can use this pattern:

```
for( map_type::iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ) {
   if( condition_to_erease ) map.erase( it++ );
   else ++i;
}
```

Why `map.erase( it++ );` works? Because it is basically equivalent to this code:

```
map::iterator tmp = it;
++it;
map.erase( tmp );
```

You should understand semantics of postfics/prefics operators if you want to use C++ effectively.

For c++11 you can also use this:

```
for( auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ) {
   if( condition_to_erease ) it = map.erase( it );
   else ++i;
}
```

I think in Visual C++ `std::map::erase()` also returned iterator, but that was not in standard.